# How to get count of each column in a SQL(Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have data like below and trying to get the count of each column per row . How to do it in a SQL/ POSTGRESQL ?

| Movie | Horror | Comedy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Y | Y |
| bbb | N | N |
| CCC | Y | N |
| DDD | Y | Y |

How to get the count of each column with a Y in POSTGRES with the expected output like this

| Category | count |
| --- | --- |
| Horror | 3 |
| Comedy | 2 |

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest method is `union all`:

```
select 'Horror', count(*)
from t
where horror = 'Y'
union all
select 'Comedy', count(*)
from t
where Comedy = 'Y';
```

But in Postgres, I would instead suggest a lateral join:

```
select genre, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('Horror', horror), ('Comedy', comedy)
     ) v(genre, flag)
where flag = 'Y'
group by genre;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the POSTGRES solution. That worked